# Facebook and Twitter sharing is missing in Notification Center

Tags: macos

On Yosemite the direct posting of both Facebook and Twitter is missing in Notification Center. How can I put it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Notification center
2. Click on "edit" button at the bottom
3. Select "Social"

[image]

**Edit :**

If "Social" is not here follow the Boti answer :

`'System Preferences'/Extensions/Today/Social`

Comment: The Social wasn't there in the edit section until I turned on this: 'System Preferences'/Extensions/Today/Social

Comment: @Boti Strange... I have edited my answer with yours.

Answer (score 1):

I found where I can turn it on.

'System Preferences'/Extensions/Today/Social